# Chef include list of packages in text file

Tags: ruby, debian, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm new to chef and planning for disaster recovery plan such that will be having all my configuration files, list of packages installed on system in chef cookbooks. I wondering how could i mention a text file in recipe for the package installation.

I have taken list of packages with

```
dpkg --get-selections > packages.txt.
```

I would like chef to read a package from that list one by one and install it. Would be great if someone can guide me on this.

Thanks,
Swaroop.

Comment: I'm not sure you're taking it the right way at all. Your best bet would be to recreate the machines with cookbooks (installing and configuring with your needs), once you have a correct copy fully automatised you can drop the actual server and rebuild it with your cokobooks.

Comment: I agree with @Tensibai. This is not a good way to approach Chef... you should be thinking about replicating "state", not process.

Comment: Sure, maybe a backup for disaster recovery and a new chef cookbook for setting the machine up is the smarter solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Blueprint](http://devstructure.com/blueprint/#puppet-chef) could help you for your task. It inspects the system and generates a chef cookbook out of it.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried it, yet. But it looks very interesting.

Answer (score -1):

I am not aware of a way to read a file from a cookbook. But you can install a number of packages with the following code in a recipe:

```
%w{
package-1
package-2
}.each do |pkg|
  package pkg
end
```

Comment: And why Not using ruby to takes the list from file on the local machine ?

Comment: Then you have to get the file onto the disk, sure.

Comment: a remote_file or cookbook_file ran at compile time before the ruby should do. I wonder if declaring ressources (package here) within a ruby_block works. I should try this one day

Comment: Sure, using pure Ruby you can read the file (optionally after downloading it from somewhere) and define the resources similar to the code above. This happens during compile time. Reading from a `remote_file` would not work during one chef run.

Comment: ... except you [add the resources during run time]( https://sethvargo.com/changing-chef-resources-at-runtime/).